# Lock on a branch removed after checkin

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Trying to lock down 2 old branches for check-in. When I check-in pending changes I see

> All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server.

The branches are then showing as unlocked. How do I perma-lock the branches for check-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking only works when your workspace is configured as a **server workspace**. After locking a file only other users with a server workspace will be aware of the lock.

According to your description and warning message, seems you are working with a local workspace.

For local workspace, you need to use **permissions** or **check-in policies** to prevent changes to a branch.

- Simply deny [contribute of check-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#tfvc) for all users on that 2 old
  branches if you want to use permission.
- You could kindly refer Martin's solution--[Branch Policies for
  TFVC](https://nkdagility.com/blog/branch-policies-tfvc/) if you want to use branch policy.